# Generics and methods

Tags: java, generics

```
public void delete10(){
    T s = null;
    try {
        s=x.pop();          
        while(s.avg()<10)
            s=x.pop();
}
```

I'm getting `The method avg() is undefined for the type T` .Now I understand `avg()` isn't implemented on type `T` but it's implemented on the types that I will use instead of `T` for this generic. How can I make it right?

```
public E pop() throws EmptyStackException {
    if (empty()) {
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
    E result = top.item;
    top = top.next;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: could you paste a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Can you please post the class definition (i.e. public class Foo<E> ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the avg method is declared in an interface Averageable, your class should be declared as

```
public class MyClass<T extends Averageable>
```

Answer (score 5):

Have an interface with the `avg` method listed.  Then when you declare `T`, write `T extends yourInterface`.